# ¿Cómo convertir un float en un date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Me han dado una tabla cuya fecha es un float y tiene el formato dd/mm/yyyy, lo que quiero es convertir el float a date.

fechaFloat
20082007  ----> 20-08-2007

Estoy intentando con esta consulta pero no me da resultados

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(int,fechaFloat)),105) FROM Mitabla
```

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Porque es float?

Comment: asi me lo han dado la tabla, no depende de mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tiene una versión de SQL Server 2008 o superior, puedes usar [`TRY_PARSE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), por ejemplo:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(FORMAT(TRY_CAST(fechaFloat AS INT),'00/00/0000') AS DATE USING 'es-ES')
       FROM Mitabla
```

Detalle:

- Básicamente, convertimos el `float` a un entero, formateamos la cadena y finalmente la convertimos el dato en un `date`.
- [`TRY_PARSE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), hace dos cosas muy interesantes (1) convierte una fecha asumiendo una configuración regional y (2) retorna `NULL` en vez de disparar un error en caso de no poder convertir la cadena
- [`TRY_CAST()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) igual que la función anterior, "intenta" la conversión y retorna `NULL` en caso de no ser posible.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección !! gracias